# wp_list_categories() add span to the category name

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, categories, wp-list-categories

I've tried a heap of "solutions" but non allow me add a simple

```
<span></span>
```

using functions.php /default-widgets.php
 to the category name, eg.

```
<li><a><span></span>Category 1</a></li>
```

the closest I've come replaces the category post count using str_replace.
I don't want to call the widget straight from the theme because it messes up the order or use jquery, is their a way of doing this "easily" or will WP not allow it.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Definately the easiest way is to edit the corefiles.

If your using wordpress 3.2.1, go to the folder wp-includes and look for **category-template.php**

And go to line 874...

```
$link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')';
```

and add in what markup you need too, for example **span** and removing the brackets.

```
$link .= '<span>' . intval($category->count) . '</span>';
```

and Voila

Comment: Editing WordPress core files is NOT recommended.